# Reorder a vector with wrap around in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a simple vector `x` in R. It is in the order 'a','b','c','d'. Is there a function that would take the vector and reorder it with wrap around? For example, how can I get `x` to be 'c','d','a','b'?

```
#Vector x
> x <- letters[1:4]
> x
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

#What I want:
> somefcn(x, 3)
[1] "c" "d" "a" "b"
```

Comment: That's a vector, not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- letters[1:4]
shiftnum <- 3
c(x[shiftnum:length(x)],x[1:shiftnum-1])

[1] "c" "d" "a" "b"
```

Is a very rough way to do, but it works