# Is there a simple way in R to access negative elements' position in a vector?

Tags: r, vector, indexing

say I have the following vector:

```
v = c(1:8)
```

and I would like to access the elements 7,8,1,2,3 in that order. That is, something like

```
v[-2:3]
```

would be great. Is there a simple way to access these negative positions, i.e., elements from `n` before last to `m`?

Comment: I meant the "negative positions" in the vector, i.e. the last would be -1, the one before last would be -2, and so on

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47292561/324364

Comment: You may use `tail` and `head`. It is `tail(v,2)` to get last two numbers and `head(v,3)` to get first three numbers.

Comment: For completeness, `c(tail(v, 2), head(v, 3))`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns: Thanks for the suggestion. I had the same idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tail` and `head` (different then the duplicate one):

```
c(tail(v,2),head(v,3))
```

OR we can use `union` to combine the answer:

```
union(tail(v,2),head(v,3))
```

Output:

```
[1] 7 8 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the modulus operator (i.e., the remainder):

```
v[-2:3 %% (length(v)+1)]
```

Output:

```
[1] 7 8 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other options using negative elements' position:
`c(v[-6:-1], v[1:3])` or `c(v[-c(1:6)], v[1:3])`